# Flutter error even when the backend (django-rest_auth) send status code 200

Tags: django, flutter, authentication, post, request

when I try to sign in with backend (django), the status code showed by the back end is correct :  "POST /auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50

but the flutter side have an error:

```dart
  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {

    final url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/auth/login/');

    try {
      print('number 1');

      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: (<String, String>{
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
          }));

      print('number 2');

      print(response.statusCode);

      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData.toString());


      _token = responseData['key'];

      notifyListeners();
      final userData = json.encode({
        'token': _token,
      });
      // prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    } catch (error) {
      print("error2");
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

can someone help me please.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide the request payload output to show how Django is returning the token? And, if is possible, provide the Flutter error stack trace.

Comment: can you share app logs.

Comment: Hello, Django return the token like this :
{
    "key": "dc7e96ed776bc44d013b44fdfe560a616c64646f"
}

sorry i'm beginner, can you tell me how can I have app logs for you ?